# Blazor QuickGrid Column Width - How to set?

Tags: blazor, quickgrid

Is there a way to set a Blazor QuickGrid's columns to a 'fixed' specific width; rather that what seems to be the default whereby columns always adjust to the width of their contents?

Without this capability, I'm finding that as I 'paginate' through the QuickGrid's contents, the grid changes its overall width with practically every page; presumably for the reason I described above.  I think this may result in a compromised experience for a User.

I've searched for this issue on the web, found nothing, and am almost convinced it's not possible.  I hope I'm wrong.  (Fwiw, one site even seemed to indicate that this feature might currently be 'backlogged'; but I'm hoping that's not true... or is true no longer).

Comment: Addendum: It's possible I described this wrong in my earlier post:  I may be finding that a Quickgrid perceives the column with the longest value-length and then the QuickGrid just 'squeezes' all the other columns down to accommodate its longest value.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I finally came upon a site that helped me with this issue (and a few other QuickGrid styling issues to boot).  It may not surprise many of you, but proper use of CSS begins to address... not all... but a few significant QuickGrid styling concerns (including the concern I expressed about wanting more control over QuickGrid column widths).  In hopes that this will also help others, I'll place the link to that site below:

https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/